# How to try/catch return transaction.on_commit

Tags: python, transactions, return, try-catch

I'm investigating an issue that I've narrowed down to one spot inside a method of the following format:

```
def method_shorthand(properties): 
  some stuff
  some more stuff

  return transaction.on_commit(
      lambda: external_function_call_I_do_not_control(properties))
   )
```

For a particular problem case I can reproduce, that `external_function_call_I_do_not_control` (firing a Segment event) doesn't happen/succeed, though I've determined all the info is correct right up until that point. For this codebase, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, so I'm predicting either:

- the commit isn't actually happening (seems unlikely; this function is called as the very last step of a successful-until-then block of code)
- the commit happens or there's no active transaction (in which case this just executes), but when this function call happens it barfs in some way- my money's on this one

So I'd like to add some kind of try/catch block in this external function line, so that if there's an exception when it runs, I can catch that, log the info, and see what's the matter so I can fix it. The problem is it's all within return transaction.on_commit, so everything I try seems to be the wrong syntax, and looking around I haven't been able to find an example of doing this.

Is there a safe way to add a try/catch block inside this return transaction.on_commit? Any other ideas for getting in there to troubleshoot, since the actual function call is external and I can't alter the code for logging/debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a lambda, use a whole function, which lets you do more complicated things than a lambda (which is usually just a direct input -> output map).

```
def method_shorthand(properties): 
  some stuff
  some more stuff

  def oncommit():
      try:
          external_function_call_I_do_not_control(properties)
      except Exception as e:
          # do whatever error handling needs to be done

  return transaction.on_commit(oncommit)
```

Comment: Ah this looks like a good way to break it out- will try and answer back- thank you!!!

Comment: this was very helpful! I am able to do this as I was hoping, BUT that lambda had been added intentionally last fall, so I think it's necessary there (and all sorts of tests fail when I take it out).  It sounds like lambda is used when we need to pass a function (rather than the result of a function), so I wonder if I can figure out where/when it finally executes and add my try/except *there* instead? It sounds like today's mission will be reading more about lambda....

Comment: Once they've been created, there is no difference between a lambda and a function. They are indistinguishable. The only difference is that a lambda can be written inline, and is a simple input/output. Note how `transaction.on_commit` passes `oncommit`, not `oncommit()` - it passes the function without calling it, which is the same as would be done with the lambda.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that distinction- interesting. I've tried to keep as close to the original code as possible (which does include the "(properties)" so I guess that does do the function call)- and just add extra handling. Is it unusual that the original source code has a lambda function where it *does* seem to make the call, rather than just passing the function name?

Comment: @DianeKaplan The reason the original code has a lambda there is probably because `transaction.on_commit()` wants a function with 0 arguments, but `external_function...()` requires one argument. The lambda serves as an intermediary that allows you to effectively turn the one-argument function into a zero-argument function (since, after all, at the time you're declaring it, you already know what `properties` is, so it may as well be a constant).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! You're able to summarize this so clearly- I really appreciate it. One other question I guess: you mentioned that lambda doesn't let you do more complicated things- (and maybe that's why that try/except block only seems to work when I remove the lambda). Does that mean if I need to keep the lambda there in order to please transaction.on_commit, then a try/except just won't work in there, and I should instead try to add that outside where I call "method_shorthand" in the first place?

Comment: The problem with lambdas is just a problem of syntax - they have to consist of exactly one expression, and the interpreter will yell at you if you step out of bounds. They exist for the sake of convenience when you have a quick transformation or something that you need to pass to something, but don't want to spend time writing an entire method for it (this is more of a problem in other languages, e.g. Java, where a one-line lambda/closure saves you fifteen lines and a new sourcefile). Anything that you'd usually pass a lambda for, will also accept any other object that can be called.